# subroutine calling another subroutine (in my case dsyev)

Tags: fortran, gfortran, lapack, fortran95

I am having a main program, which needs a subroutine(say 1) to execute, but the same subroutine(1), needs another subroutine(say 2), in my case it is dsyev(standard matrix diagonalization, by LAPACK).

Now, I am facing a problem, whenever I am passing a matrix to my subroutine 1 which writes corresponding Hamiltonian matrix to it, then the it calls subroutine 2 inside subroutine 1, for diagonalizing the Hamiltonian; for which as result I will get the energy eigenvalues in my main program. I am getting *************** instead of energy eigenvalues.

```
PROGRAM MAIN
! Variable intialization
!................
do i=1, N
  call subroutine1(n, Matrix1 ,EIG )

   write(3,'(100G5.5)')(EIG(K),K=1,siz)

    !
    !
    !
    !
enddo

end program

subroutine subroutine1(n, Matrix2, EIG )

  CALL init_random_seed()

!  body of the function

! writing Matrix2 to a Hamiltonian(which is done fruitfully)

! Diagonilizing Hamiltonian

  CALL DSYEV('Vectors', 'Upper', SIZ, HAMIL, LDA, EIG, WORK, LWORK, INFO)

end subroutine

subroutine init_random_seed()

! Standard random no. generator

end subroutine
```

Comment: Sounds like the format statement you are using to print your data doesn't have wide enough fields.  Try just using G format instead of F format or print the results in free format.  Alternatively, show us the code where you are printing your data and someone will advise you.

Comment: Ya I am using _'(100g5.5)'_. Code is very long, to be shown here. Ya I can explain the gist of it.

Comment: Don't show us the gist of your code, make the modification suggested by @cup and let us know what happens.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark It is shown on the sixth line of my code. I already told that, I am having proper format. No point of modification.

Comment: 'g5.5', when applied to a real value is likely to use 2 to 4 characters for the exponent (e.g. 'e-23', 'e+1', etc), one character for the decimal point, and the remaining characters (if any) for the significand and some blanks between fields.  In my experience a compiler will often print 5 '*'s rather than squeeze a real value into a 5 character field.

Comment: when I am printing eigenvalues in the same format inside subroutine1, then i am getting proper values. You are right about the  5 '*'s. How to get rid of it.

Comment: the minimum field with for `g` format should be `d+8` (assuming you want to guarantee a space between values), try `g12.4` for example.  If your values are changing between program units thats a different isse, but first use a format descriptor that makes sense so you see the actual numbers

Comment: thanks george, it worked